# insert statement error On linked server (POSTGRESQL)

Tags: postgresql, linked-server, data-lake

I am trying to fetch and insert the data from one table to another on a linked server.

```
with datum as 
(
select * from openquery([DDL_64],'SELECT e.*
, ib.sales_order_number                                              IB_SALES_ORDER_NUMBER
, ib.sales_order_date                   IB_SALES_ORDER_DATE
, ib.sales_order_type                   IB_SALES_ORDER_TYPE
, ib.model_number                       IB_MODEL_NUMBER
, ib.product_item_number                IB_ITEM_NUMBER
, ib.product_item_description           IB_MODEL_DESC
, ib.install_base_status                IB_STATUS
, ib.cs_customer_name                   IB_Install_Customer
, ib.install_at_country_name            IB_Install_Country
, ib.model_so_line_num                  IB_Model_SO_Line_Number
, current_date                          last_Run_Date

FROM ws_sls_core.dd_enclosures_forarsdashboard e 
left join  ws_sls_core.w_customer_ib_profile ib 
                ON (e.encl_serial = ib.serial_number and ib.model_number not in (''NA'',''UN'')) limit 10')
)
insert into openquery([DDL_64],'select sn1,encl,encl_model,encl_serial,encl_slots,encl_state,encl_oem_name,encl_owm_value,parsed_ts,disk,disk_slot,disk_manf,disk_capacity,disk_sn,disk_type,disk_firmware,disk_model,id,asupid,sn,epoch,external,model,model_str,sn_valid,eth0mac,tz,lic_feature,lic_key,ib_sales_order_number,ib_sales_order_date,ib_sales_order_type,ib_model_number,ib_item_number,ib_model_desc,ib_status,ib_install_customer,ib_install_country,ib_model_so_line_number,last_run_date
from ws_sls_core.dd_enclosure_ib_f_temp ')
select * from datum
```

I am getting the error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DDL_64" returned message
> "the driver cound't identify inserted rows". Msg 7343, Level 16, State
> 2, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DDL_64"
> could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".

I have checked and am using the 64bit version of SSMS & ODBC setup.
PS: Select statement is working fine. I have limited it to 10 rows for testing purposes.
Any input is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How is this related to PostgreSQL?  Looks like SQL Server only.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Target server is Data lake and POSTGRES is being used there.

Comment: Hi All,
Can anyone suggest something? Thank you!